# Ubuntu VS Windows partitioning, 2TB limit

Tags: windows, raid, installation, gpt

I have a server with a 3ware 9690sa-i8 raid card installed. I have configured a raid with a size of 12TB which i would like to use for Windows. It seems whenever the partition table is MSDOS the limit of a partiton is 2TB. Changing to the GPT partiton table under a live cd with parted lets me instead create a partiton containing all the available disk space. But when trying to install Windows on that partion, it complains about the GPT partition table and will not continue.

How could i overcome this, and why did I not experience any troubles installing Ubuntu on the same setup/hardware?

Comment: Its not very sensible to put your OS boot partitions on a massive data drive.  Keeping them seperated will likely save you hassle down the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows can only boot from a GPT partitioned disk in UEFI-Mode, not in legacy BIOS mode. Linux doesn't have this limitation.

It might be possible your system doesn't offer UEFI at all. You have to check your servers BIOS to see if you can switch it to UEFI boot mode.